# BindingAdapter in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I am following this [course](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding/) about RecyclerView and Databinding.

I've read [What is the use of binding adapter in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305560/what-is-the-use-of-binding-adapter-in-android).

Other than make [custom/more complex setter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters#kotlin), what is the benefit of using `BindingAdapter` over the "normal" way ? Is there a gain in performance ?

## **Version1:**

- **xml:**

  ```xml
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sleep_length"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      ...
      tools:text="Wednesday" />
  ```
- **Adapter**:

  ```kotlin
  fun bind(item: SleepNight) {
      val res = itemView.context.resources
      sleepLength.text = convertDurationToFormatted(item.startTimeMilli, item.endTimeMilli, res)
  }
  ```

## **Version2 (DataBinding):**

- **xml:**

  ```xml
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sleep_length"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      app:sleepDurationFormatted="@{sleep}"
      ...
      tools:text="Wednesday" />
  ```
- **Adapter**:

  ```kotlin
  fun bind(item: SleepNight) {
      binding.sleep = item
  }
  ```
- **BindingUtils:**

  ```kotlin
  @BindingAdapter("sleepDurationFormatted")
  fun TextView.setSleepDurationFormatted(item: SleepNight){
         text = convertDurationToFormatted(item.startTimeMilli, item.endTimeMilli, context.resources)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding Adapter gives you a pretty good feature in customization of a view. 
Seems weird!.

**First**, Suppose you have an ImageView that shows the country flag.

Accept: Country code(String)

Action: Show the flag of the country, if the country code is null, make ImageView GONE.

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:setFlag"})
public static void setFlagImageView(ImageView imageView, String currencyCode) {
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    if (currencyCode != null) {
        try {
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(context.getAssets().open("flags/"+currencyCode.toLowerCase()+".png"), null);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else{
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

So now you can reuse this BindinAdapter any elsewhere.

People who loves DataBinding, see that they can reduce amount of code and write some logic in xml. Instead of helper methods.

**Second**, By databinding, you will ignore findViewById, because a generated file would be created for you.

Regarding performance, I don't find in official documentation any indicate that BindingAdapter increases performance.

Comment: If you would like to refresh some views using your code, you should make the property as Bindable. 


Check my answer for this question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100508/12424486